# how to debug sql server queries

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to test some query so i tried running it inside of SQL enterprise manager and i get the following error:

**EXECUTE permission denied on object 'sp_enable_sql_debug', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.**

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be a [member of the sysadmin role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1bhybwz(VS.80).aspx) to run this system stored proc to [enable debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0fk6z6e(VS.80).aspx).

This is different to having permissions to run *your* code which *you* created in *your* database

[More info from a blog entry from the "CLR Integration team at SQL Server"](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlclr/archive/2006/07/07/659332.aspx)... Skip to 3rd paragraph if you have short attention span about why sysadmin rights are needed

Answer (score 0):

Your case seems to be a simple question of permissions - if you can't even execute your code, you can't debug it.

Once you can execute your code and still run into problems, SQL Server 2008 does offer a T-SQL debugger inside SQL Server Management Studio.

- http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1695
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=618LE_FZCxI

Quite useful if you need to debug complicated T-SQL script batches or stored procs!

Marc